# Prove that $f \circ g$ is injective if $f$ and $g$ are injective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Is this proof correct?

Proof:

Let $g:A \rightarrow B$, $f:B \rightarrow C$ and $x,y\in A$.

$x=y \iff g(x)=g(y) \iff f(g(x))=f(g(y)) \iff f\circ g(x)=f \circ g(y)$.

We have proved $f\circ g(x)=f \circ g(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

Hence, if $f$ and $g$ are injective, so is $f \circ g$.

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea when you're introducing $f$ and $g$ to also write "Let $f$ and $g$ be injections". At this level, I think you should also state exactly where you use each of the hypotheses "$f$ is injective" and "$g$ is injective". It's also not necessary to have the "iff" $\iff$ arrows the whole way through, so it's cleaner to just say "suppose that $f \circ g(x) = f \circ g(y)$" and show that implies $x = y$.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely correct. Well-done!

Follow-up: show that the same holds when 'injective' is replaced by 'surjective'.